# Python regex for max year and quarter in list of column names

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

In PySpark I have a dataset with list of columns `[...'PC2020Q3', 'PC2020Q4', 'PC2021Q1', 'PC2021Q2'...]`. Every quarter there will be new column with actual year and quarter, so next one will be `'PC2021Q3'`.
I would like to create new column PC_ACT which will take only the most recent PC.

I was thinking about getting list of columns and with regex find the max year and max quarter. Something like:

```
cols = df.schema.names
rx = /regex/
colMax = cols.find(rx)
df = df.withColumn("PC_ACT", F.col(colMax))
```

How should the regex looks like to achieve always the max?

*EDIT*
There are much more columns with different names. Not only years and quarters.

Thank you very much

Comment: can't you just use `max(cols)`?

Comment: There are much more columns, not only the ones with years and quarters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the columns and then take the max:

```python
import re
colMax = max([ c for c in df.schema.names if re.match(r"PC\d{4}Q\d", c)])
```